# Is there a way to implement an "are you sure" button when deleting cells / rows / columns in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been messing around with this for a little bit.however I can't seem to crack this one. I have a order list that needs to be carefully maintained.

haven't tried much... I tried to get an ai to write this for me however it did not seem to work. I don't have much coding experience so any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event might be a good start.